# JS how to know current file name when is only domain

Tags: javascript, pathname

using **window.location.pathname** for page https://google.com/home.html result will be **"/home.html"**

when file name is not present in url, e.g. https://google.com/ result will be **"/"**

in Sources from inspector is index

[image]

is there a way to obtain current file name

Answer (score 2):

No.

The browser has no insight into what process the HTTP server does to convert a path into a resource.

It's entirely possible that the content is dynamically generated and there is no "file".